# How to see the voltage of the output on LCD?

Tags: voltage

I designed a circuit which has a output voltage and I want to see that voltage on LCD and how do I do that?

Do I have to use analog to digital converter and programmed it and connect it to LCD?

Comment: Did You have LCD driver/controller ? Can You post that circuit or what components are used?

Comment: I don't use LCD driver or controller. It has an op-amp and some resistors. It was used as a differential op-amp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of device created for this sort of situation is called *panel meter*.  A modern panel meter is an LCD display (or an LED display) with a built-in ADC (analog to digital converter).

A typical panel meter is hard-wired (as opposed to programmable).  It takes a certain range of voltages and displays it.

[image]
Here's a sample of a run-off-the-mill LCD panel meter.
Notice that it has got few outside connections: voltage to measure, power, ground.

Comment: An observation- a lot of the cheapest ones now seem to be using flash microcontroller chips, so they are (at least theoretically) reprogrammable.

Comment: But I want to be able to read AC voltage. Does it also work with AC?

Comment: @Harry.P, yes it works also with AC.

Comment: @Harry , some panel meters can work with AC.  You'd have to check the datacheets on a product-by-product basis.  Another option [obviously] is to change the design of your circuit such that it outputs DC derived from AC.